# grep whole words made of only uppercase letters

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep, bsd

Seems like this is rather simple, but I'm having trouble.

I have a text document that looks, for example, like this:

> This is a 
>   TEXT DOCUMENT with 
>   SOME capitalized words 
>   BUT NOT all of them are 
>   ALL CAPS 
>   iPhone

What I would like is to parse this document and match only whole words made up of only uppercase letters, like so:

> TEXT DOCUMENT 
>   SOME 
>   BUT NOT 
>   ALL CAPS

I wrote this:

```
grep -o "\w[[:upper:]]\w" Untitled.txt
```

This gets pretty close but, alas, returns this:

> TEX
>   DOC
>   UME
>   SOM
>   BUT
>   NOT
>   ALL
>   CAP
>   iPh

...which, candidly, I don't understand.

So: what might I be missing? egrep doesn't work very well under OS X because I'm limited by FreeBSD's grep (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD), I guess, so many of the solutions I've found for egrep that seem like they would work don't work as expected.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `\b` rather than `\w`?

Comment: Based on what answer you accepted it seems that outputting each all-uppercase word _on its own line_ is what you want, unlike what your expected sample output suggests; perhaps you can revise your expected sample output accordingly (with an explanatory note, given that at least one respondent has tried to solve the different problem suggested by the original sample output).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You miss `*` and also `\w` is any word character. Correct regexp is:

```
\<[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*\>
```

`\<` `\>` match word boundaries

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark yours as the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107161/45375):

`grep`'s `-E` option allows use of *extended* regular expression, which includes quantifier `+` to mean *one or more*, which simplifies the solution:

```
 grep -Eo '\<[[:upper:]]+\>' Untitled.txt
```

Also, as mentioned in [Benjamin W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107203/45375), `-w` can be used to match on word boundaries without having to specify it as part of the regex:

```
 grep -Ewo '[[:upper:]]+' Untitled.txt
```

Note, however, that `-w` is a *nonstandard* option (but both BSD/OSX and GNU `grep` implement it).

---

As for `egrep`: it is nothing more than an (effective) alias of `grep -E`, which, as stated, activates support for *extended* regular expressions, but the exact set of features is *platform-dependent*.

Additionally, only GNU `grep` supports the `-P` option to support PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression), which offer even more features and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for this. Interestingly, the first command in your answer is noticeably faster than the second command. (The actual text document I'm using is very long.)

Comment: @celestialroad: That is indeed curious, thanks for the feedback; unrelated: I've added a note about `egrep`.

Answer (score 1):

The example output shows multiple space separated uppercase words on the same line, which can be achieved with

```
$ grep -ow '[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:space:]]*[[:upper:]]' infile
TEXT DOCUMENT
SOME
BUT NOT
ALL CAPS
```

Any sequence starting and ending with an uppercase character, and uppercase characters or whitespace between them. `-o` returns the matches only, and `-w` makes sure that we don't match something like `WORDlowercase`.

Comment: `-w` is helpful, but note that there's no point in including `[:space:]`, as a word by definition never has spaces in it. While your command still works as intended with _GNU_ `grep`, it does _not_ with _BSD_ `grep`, which the OP uses.

Comment: @mklement0 So it still only returns single words? I looked up the `-w` option in the BSD grep manpage and thought that "as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`" would return multiple words... apparently not.

Comment: I know realize that you were trying to return multiple contiguous uppercase words on a single line, as in the OP's sample output.
I suspect that's not what they actually wanted, though, based on what answer they accepted: it seems that outputting each uppercase word on its own line is sufficient.
What BSD Grep actually does in your case is to only match lines _solely_ made up of uppercase letters - don't ask me why.
Also note that even with GNU Grep your command is quirky: trailing whitespace is also captured if a line's last word is an all-uppercase word.

Comment: @mklement0 There goes "short and elegant"... `grep -o '[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:space:]]*[[:upper:]]'` would work for multiple words. Waiting to see if the question gets updated and removing this answer maybe.

Comment: Nicely done (++), this now works with both GNU and BSD Grep. I suggest you update your answer, and also add a preamble that explains how your answer solves a different problem and why - then I think it still has value.

Comment: @mklement0 Turns out you *do* need the `-w`, but not for the example input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
grep -o -E "\<[[:upper:]]+\>" Untitled.txt
```

- `-E` activates extended regexp, this makes `+` available which stand for 1 or more repetitions
- `\<` and `\>` are anchor marking the begin and end of a word
- the whole regex means a sequence of one or more uppercase characters that made up the whole word

Your original regexp gave you three letter matches, because `\w` stands for `[_[:alnum:]]`, so you instructed grep to match something which consists of three characters:

- the first and third from the `[_[:alnum:]]`
- the second from the [[:upper:]] range

Answer (score 0):

An "old school" RE would be fewer characters:

`grep -o '[A-Z][A-Z]*' Untitled.txt`

It uses the `-o` option to Only print matching words and matches against uppercase A through Z.

Adding `-w` to search words and `-E` to invoke the Extended regular expressions allows this one that is even shorter:

`grep -woE '[A-Z]+\>' Untitled.txt`

Comment: This would limit you to ASCII letters only, so it should only be used if you explicitly want to exclude foreign letters.